# Creating a CSS3 3D rotation that swings in like a door

Tags: html, css, css-animations, gsap

I'm trying to use CSS 3D animations to swing in some elements like a door.

I want to achieve an effect like how the 9 tiles swing in on this site: http://www.ge.com/thegestore

Right now I can get a rotation effect using the TweenMax library, but it's not quite right. My element is rotating in over the top instead from the inside.

Anyone know how to achieve the swing in from the inside effect, using TweenMax or just regular CSS?

See code: https://jsfiddle.net/0a0osq6a/3/

```
TweenMax.set('#flip-me',{
  rotationX: 180,
  transformOrigin: "top center"
});

var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:0, repeatDelay: 0});

tl.add (TweenMax.to("#flip-me", .8, {
  css: {
    rotationX: 0,
    transformOrigin: "top center"
  },
  ease: Cubic.easeInOut
}));
tl.play();
```

Comment: there are 2 properties called `transform-perspective` and `perspective` available in CSS3 (and ultimately available in GSAP as well) that I think you need to use here. Take a look at this **[modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/wjLndxLt/)**. Read about more `transformPerspective` and `perspective` from a GSAP standpoint **[here](https://greensock.com/css3/)**.

Comment: Adding transform-perspective did the trick! Thank you! See updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0a0osq6a/4/

Comment: @TahirAhmed Write this up as an answer so intersection can accept it.

Comment: Also intersection you should post your working completed code here as an answer so others with the same or similar problem can learn from it.

Comment: @TahirAhmed: mpactMEDIA is correct. You should post your solution as an answer. I am thinking of posting a pure CSS solution but you deserve to post your solution first :)

Comment: thanks guys for the suggestion. posted as an answer. please do share a pure CSS solution as well for me to learn @Harry :)

Comment: @mpactMedia, OK, posted an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution using pure CSS. The key property is again the `perspective` (which is equivalent to `transformPerspective` described in Tahir Ahmed's answer). This property along with the transform's origin and the rotation angles produce the swinging door effect.

In the below snippet, I've used CSS animations to auto-trigger the swinging door effect but we can add it to the element when a user action (like `:hover`) occurs also.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.top {
  transform-origin: top; /* equivalent to 50% 0% */
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(-90deg);
  animation: swing 1s cubic-bezier(0.75,0.4,1,1) forwards 1s;
  /* animation syntax - [name] [duration] [timing-function] [fill-mode] [delay] */
}
.bottom {
  transform-origin: bottom; /* equivalent to 50% 100% */
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(90deg);
  animation: swing 1s cubic-bezier(0.75,0.4,1,1) forwards 1s;
}
.left {
  transform-origin: left; /* equivalent to 0% 50% */
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateY(90deg);
  animation: swing 1s cubic-bezier(0.75,0.4,1,1) forwards 1s;
}
.right {
  transform-origin: right; /* equivalent to 100% 50% */
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateY(-90deg);
  animation: swing 1s cubic-bezier(0.75,0.4,1,1) forwards 1s;
}
@keyframes swing {
  to {
    transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes swing-alt {
  to {
    transform: perspective(200px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='top'>This swings from the top</div>
<div class='bottom'>This swings from the bottom</div>
<div class='left'>This swings from the left</div>
<div class='right'>This swings from the right</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing it as an answer.

The solution to your problem is using a property called `transformPerspective`.

> The perspective CSS property determines the distance between the z=0 plane and the user in order to give to the 3D-positioned element some perspective

**[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/perspective)**.

> transformPerspective affects only the element that is being animated, making it look as though it has its own distinct vanishing point in its own 3D space.

...

> perspective should be applied to the parent of the element(s) being animated - an element's perspective affects all of its children, allowing them to share a common vanishing point

**[Link](https://greensock.com/css3/)**.

Take a look at this **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/wjLndxLt/)** as an example. Hope this helps.

**JavaScript:**

```
TweenMax.set(document.body, { margin: 0, padding: 0, overflow: 'hidden' });

TweenMax.staggerFromTo('.flip-me', 0.8, {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  yPercent: -50,
  xPercent: -50,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  textAlign: 'center',
  rotationX: 90,
  transformOrigin: 'top center',
  transformPerspective: 400,
  backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
  cycle: {
    x: [-200, -100, 0, 100, 200],
    backgroundColor: ['#c00', '#0c0']
  }
}, {
  repeat: -1,
  yoyo: true,
  rotationX: 0,
  ease: Power2.easeInOut
}, 0.1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working after following Tamir Ahmed's suggestion to use transformPerspective.

Here's the updated TweenMax JS:

```
TweenMax.set('#flip-me',{
rotationX: -90,
transformOrigin: "0 0",
transformPerspective: '1000'
});

var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:0, repeatDelay: 0});

tl.add (TweenMax.to("#flip-me", .8, {
          css: {
              rotationX: 0,
              transformOrigin: "0 0"
          },
          ease: Cubic.easeInOut
          }));
 tl.play();
```

See JSFiddle for full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0a0osq6a/4/

Answer (score 0):

Creating a swinging door effect is pretty straight forward using CSS and or GSAP. Just make sure you have the CSS setup right with `transform-style`, `perspective`, and `backface-visibility`.

GSAP Swinging Door Example:

http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/NxVMBx

HTML markup:

```
<div id="cardWrapper">
   <div class="card">
      <div class="cardFace front"><p>FRONT</p></div>
      <div class="cardFace back"><p>BACK</p></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS GSAP:

```
// 3D Swinging Door GSAP

// setup initial CSS properties
TweenLite.set("#cardWrapper", {perspective: 1000 });
TweenLite.set(".card", { transformStyle: "preserve-3d" });
TweenLite.set(".back", { rotationY: -180 });
TweenLite.set([".back", ".front"], { backfaceVisibility: "hidden" });

// create new timeline in paused state
var tl = new TimelineMax({
   paused: true
});

// swinging door tween
tl.to(".card", 0.6, {
   rotationY: 180, 
   transformOrigin: "100% 0%", 
   ease: Cubic.easeOut
});

tl.progress(0).progress(1); /* pre-record property values */
tl.play();
```